# How to data bind simple ViewModel to WPF Datagrid?

Tags: mdriven

that's perhaps an absolute newbye question.

I try to bind a simple Viewmodel Person.allinstances with Firstname: string, Lastname: string to WPF DataGrid.

ViewModel:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHN7F.png)

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ecoVM:ViewModelContent x:Key="VM1" ViewModelName="AllPersons" EcoSpaceType="{x:Type ecospace:RelativesEcoSpace}" ></ecoVM:ViewModelContent>
</Window.Resources>

           <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource VM1}">
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ?????}" />
           </Grid>
```

Code Behind:

(Resources["VM1"] as ViewModelContent).SetEcoSpace(_es);
(Resources["VM1"] as ViewModelContent).RootObject = ???;

How should I do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the ViewModel - check the CodeGen-checkbox.
[image]

Then CodeGen - and you have a strongly typed VM at your disposal

Use like this:

```
xmlns:MyVm="clr-namespace:MDrivenMinimalWecpof3.ViewModelCodeGen_FirstView"
...
<MyVm:FirstView x:Key="MyVm"  ></MyVm:FirstView>
...
<Grid Grid.Row="2" DataContext="{StaticResource MyVm}">
  <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllSomeClass }" AutoGenerateColumns="True"></DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

In code behind you set the EcoSpace and possibly root:

`(this.Resources["MyVm"] as ViewModelCodeGen_FirstView.FirstView).SetEcoSpace(_es);`

Comment: That has helped, thanks. Now I would like to view/edit  the currently selected Person. I have set a simple StackPanel with 2 TextBoxes. How should I data bind these? I have tried already over DataContext={StaticResource PersonView}   <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" and over using vCurrent_AllPersonsView, but no success. Interesting I get no data binding errors, but it does not work

Comment: I have solved it over binding to Datagrid over ElementName, but I don't like this solution. Is there a way to bind it over Viewmodels?

Comment: Once you bind the ViewModel to DataContext of a parent control - dataContext is flowing downwards in WPF - so adding new controls inside parent will get same context. For example add a viewModelColumn on root called FirstNameA with ocl vCurrent_SomeClass.FirstName - now you can do {Binding Path=FirstNameA, Mode=TwoWay} in wpf.